# Sending self sms from iPhone via flutter

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, one-time-password

I'm using the flutter_otp plugin for SMS.

It works fine on Android but I get this error on iPhone.

I tried different format for phone number but still the same error.

```
    <asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
#2      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:542:29)
#3      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:528:64)
#8      new SmsSender._private (package:sms/sms.dart:313:44)
#9      new SmsSender (package:sms/sms.dart:307:23)
#10     FlutterOtp.sendOtp (package:flutter_otp/flutter_otp.dart:37:28)
#11     SignUpViewModel.sendOTP (package:checkin/backend/viewModels/signup_view_model.dart:122:17)
#12     SignUpView.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:checkin/backend/views/signup_view.dart:93:39)
#13     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
#14     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
#15     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
#16     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256:7)
#17     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158:27)
#18     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224:20)
#19     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
#20     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
#21     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
#22     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
#26     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
#27     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
(elided 7 frames from dart:async)
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Did you try to flutter clean and restart xcode . then Run again?

Comment: Yes. I even deleted the driveddata and all. But keep getting the same message

Comment: `flutter_otp` depends on `sms 0.2.4` package which doesnt support ios  according to the documentation here `https://pub.dev/packages/sms`

Comment: Maybe try the fl_join option

Comment: @MJMontes Thanks. I've been at it for a while now.

Comment: @Nimzo I can't find fl_join